# How to show the sql django runs?

Tags: django

Yep, so there is a question like this on SO already, with the answer:

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> connection.queries
[{'sql': 'SELECT polls_polls.id,polls_polls.question,polls_polls.pub_date FROM polls_polls',
'time': '0.002'}]
```

the problem is, i have no idea what  that means. I can see it is being run from a console, but my django project, well, it runs as a django project!

Where do i put this code? In the html view? In the view.py? In the model.py?

thanks!

Comment: try [django-debug-toolbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar)

Comment: have you tried python manage.py sqlall [appname] ?

Comment: @okm, that is so correct it should be an answer. If it's an entire view you'd like to debug, the debug toolbar is your answer. Otherwise if you'd like to know what a single query generates, you can `print my_queryset.query`

Answer (score 2):

In debug mode, you could use [django-debug-toolbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar), it prints all SQLs executed, as well as callees and explains of the SQLs, and extra info such as templates invoking, request, signals, etc. Very handy indeed.

In shell, as Yuji Tomita suggests, `print queryset.query` (in legacy Django it's something like `queryset._get_sql_clause()`, just FYI) or `connection.queries` in your question.