# How many queries are being generated?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class JobApplication(models.Model):
    profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    job = models.ForeignKey(JobPost)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s" % (self.profile.full_name, self.job.get_job_name())

# in JobPost model
    def get_job_name(self):
        if self.name:
            return self.name
        name = "%s - %s" % (self.production.name, self.position.position)
        return name
```

How would I figure out how many queries are being generated when a `JobApplication` queryset is produced? Usually I do `print Model.objects.filter().query`. How would I do it in this case to see it?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695305/how-to-show-the-sql-django-runs/10701259#10701259  Use `django.db.connection.queries` and `django-debug-toolbar` to show executed SQLs.

Comment: @okm what about for sql that is executed only in the template? For example, if I am doing a `for` loop, and I call a db method that invokes a db call -- I can't do anything in the view here. (As a side note, I'm using debug-toolbar already)

Comment: The debug-toolbar could collect and show SQLs that executed in template

Comment: Also you could print `connection.queries` after the `for` loop, either in template tag or after render(in view before `return` or in a decorator or middleware)

Comment: @okm: ok thanks, How would I print `connection.queries` in a template tag?

Comment: Check [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags). Something like `from django import template; from django.db import connection; the_tag = template.Library().simple_tag(lambda: str(connection.queries))`

Comment: no need to reinvent the wheel. follow @okm 's advice and use the `django-debug-toolbar`

Comment: The [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) can be very useful for this and similar tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs,

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> connection.queries
[{'sql': 'SELECT polls_polls.id,polls_polls.question,polls_polls.pub_date FROM         polls_polls',
'time': '0.002'}]
```

Reference link: [click here for docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the builtin logging tools for outputting every generated query to the terminal on the development server. Add this to your settings.py file:

```
# settings.py
LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG' if DEBUG else 'WARNING'
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'simple': {
            'format': '\n%(thread)d: %(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'simple'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'multiprocessing': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
        },
        'cache_logger': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
        }
    }
}
```

This way, whenever DEBUG is True you will can load a view or call a function or anything and see the generated query and the time it took to complete:

```
4072: DEBUG (0.016) SELECT "django_content_type"."id", "django_content_type"."name", "django_content_type"."app_label", "django_content_type"."model"
FROM "django_content_type" WHERE "django_content_type"."id" = 9 ; args=(9,)
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you forgot to add the logger that captures the db query: `django.db.backends`.